# A Pure Crossword Minicube

Tags: crosswords, three-dimensional

This puzzle was made as requested by [EKons](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12114/ekons), [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14524?m=51000687#51000687).

So, enjoy this three-dimensional realistic sensation!

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
>  PED
>
>  ARE
>
>  NAY
>
>
>
>  AGO
>
>  GOV
>
>  ETA
>
>
>
>  LOG
>
>  AWE
>
>  WEM
> ```
>
> note that the clue for 3 away (DOG) is "spurious"; ie, fake

Comment: Note that a better clue for 2 down would be "Period", because it's bigger than a "Point" ;)

Comment: [see this, thanks for your comment.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/era) all is correct, and the check is on it's way :)